# How to find all the Combinations of an integer number?

Tags: python, numbers, combinations

**Let's say we have given the number n = 212.
We need to make all the possible 1 digit, 2 digits, 3 digits combination to the length of a number.**

```
In this example, the length is 3.
So combinations will be [2, 1, 2, 21, 22, 12, 212].
Tell me how to do it?
Is there any method or function in python that can help me ease the problem?
```

```
Another Example:
n = 2345
combinations = [2, 3, 4, 5, 23, 24, 25, 34, 35, 45, 234, 235, 345, 2345]
```

Comment: One option is to convert the number to a string, split the string into a list, and then get all combinations of the list with itertools.

Comment: `from itertools import combinations; combis = [int("".join(combi)) for r in range(1, len(str(n))+1) for combi in combinations(str(n), r)]`

Comment: Take a look at the `powerset` recipe in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). `[''.join(x) for x in powerset(str(n)) if x]`. (Since we're working with arbitrary iterables, not real sets, it works for iterables containing duplicates like `str(212)` does.)

Comment: @chepner Nice one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

```py
from itertools import combinations

number = list(input("Kindly enter the number: "))

counter = 1

answer = []

while counter < len(number)+1:
    comb = combinations(number, counter)
    for i in list(comb):
        num = "".join(i)

        answer.append(int(num))

    counter += 1

print(list(set(answer)))
```

Comment: @MayankBhatt Working as you expected?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it's working. You had given me a very good idea to solve these types of problems.

Comment: I think you had already made the "number" variable a list and you are again making it list in combinations by doing [i for i in number] which I think is redundant. You can simply pass number iterable in the combinations like combinations(number, counter).

Comment: Very correct, I in order to provide an answer as fast as possible didn't notice that . Happy to help you, and thanks for improving my answer